# Why is the set of points where a complex polynomial does not vanish connected?

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, several-complex-variables

Let $p$ be a complex multivariate polynomial. Let $C$ be the set of those complex tuples where $p$ is nonzero. Then, $C$ is connected.

Comment: What is the question? Whether this is true? How to prove it?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/242601/3217

Answer (score 5):

You may assume without loss of generality that $p\not\equiv 0$, since otherwise $C = \varnothing$ is clearly connected.

Let $z\in C$ be any point. We will show $C$ is connected by proving that for any point $w\in C$, there is a path in $C$ between $w$ and $z$. Indeed, let $L\cong \mathbb{C}$ be the complex line connecting $z$ and $w$. Then $p|_L$ is a complex polynomial in one variable that does not vanish everywhere on $L$ (since it does not vanish at either $z$ or $w$), and hence $p$ vanishes at at most finitely many points of $L$. Thus $L\cap C$ is $\mathbb{C}$ with finitely many points removed, which is path connected. Thus there exists a path in $L\cap C$ connecting $z$ and $w$.

Comment: Dear froggie, I think you mean $L\backslash(L\cap C)$ is $\mathbb{C}$ with finitely many points removed.

Comment: @RobertAuffarth: No, I think I mean $L\cap C$ is $\mathbb{C}$ with finitely many points removed, since $C$ is defined to be the set of points where $p$ does *not* vanish.

Comment: Ah ok you're right! For a moment I thought of $C$ as the points where the polynomial vanishes. Great answer!

Answer (score 0):

I consider the more general case of an analytic set $A \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ and denote by

$$ C := \mathbb{C}^n - A$$

its complement.

In case $A = \mathbb{C}^n$ we have $C = \varnothing$ and the statement is false: The empty set is not connected.

Consider $A \subsetneq \mathbb{C}^n$. Then  $A$ is low-dimensional at each point of its points. Suppose: $C$ is not connected. Then

$$C = C_1 \cup C_2, C_1 \cap C_2 = \varnothing,$$

is a disjoint union of open, non-empty  subsets $C_i \subset C$. For $i =1,2$ define constant functions $f_i$ on $C_i$ by $f_i := i$. Both functions together define a bounded holomorphic function on $C = \mathbb{C}^n - A$. By Riemann's theorem on removable singularities the function extends to a holomorphic function $f$ on ${\mathbb C}^n$ with $f|C_i = f_i = i$. Because $f|C_1=1$ the function $f$ must be constant $=1$ on the connected set $\mathbb {C}^n$ by the identity theorem for holomorphic functions. But $f|C_2 = 2$, a contradiction, q.e.d.

So far the proof for the ususal Euclidean topology. The same results holds true also for the Zariski topology with analytic subsets of $\mathbb{C}^n$ as closed sets: The identity map between topological spaces

$$id: (\mathbb{C}^n,T_{Euclid}) \longrightarrow (\mathbb{C}^n,T_{Zariski})$$

is continous. And the image of a connected set under a continous map is connected.