# Irreducibility of a polynomial and connectedness of its zero set

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, several-complex-variables

Let $P$ be a polynomial in $\mathbb{C}[z_1,z_2,...,z_n].$ Let $Z(P)$ denotes its zero set in 
$\mathbb{C}^n.$ I have the following question:

Does the irreducibility of $P$ imply that $Z(P)$ is connected?

Comment: Which topology do you use on $\mathbb{C}^n$?

Comment: As I just found out, it doesn't make a difference. See: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/242535/a-complex-algebraic-variety-which-is-connected-in-the-usual-topology/242601#242601

Comment: Ok, but I was considering the usual topology meaning considering $\mathbb{C}^n$ as a normed vector space.

Comment: Using the link I provided, it is sufficient to prove the connectedness in the Zariski topology, which is easier: The set of zeros of a prime ideal is irreducible, which implies connectedness.

Comment: yeah that is true, if the connectedness in the Zariski topology and in the "usual topology" are same then infact we are done, as irreducibility is equivalent to connectedness in the Zariski topology.

Comment: Almost: Irreducibility is stronger than connectedness, so you get in the Zariski topology more than you need to prove your point

Comment: So, finally can we conclude that Z(P) is connected in Euclidean topology?