# Harnack's curve theorem for curves in $\textit{complex}$ projective plane?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

The [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harnack's_curve_theorem) gives the statement for algebraic curves in real projective plane.

Is the statement also true in $\textit{complex}$ projective plane? If not, is there a similar statement about number of connected components of an algebraic curve in $\mathbb{P}^2$? Is it true that number of connected components are finitely many?

Comment: In the complex case they're all connected, aren't they?

Comment: you mean all algebraic curves in $\mathbb{P}^2$ are connected? could you give me a reference for the proof?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by curve, but Zariski connected subvarieties of $\mathbb{P}^n$ should be connected in the classical topology. There's some relevant discussion [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/242535/a-complex-algebraic-variety-which-is-connected-in-the-usual-topology) and at the end [here](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~osserman/classes/248B-W12/notes/analytic.pdf). I personally don't know how to show this. Curves in $\mathbb{P}^2$ have to meet so there shouldn't be any problem with having multiple components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field. By [Bézout's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_theorem), if $C$ and $D$ are two projective curves in the projective plane $\mathbb{P}_k^2$ such that $C$ and $D$ do not have a common irreducible component, then $C$ and $D$ intersect at exactly $\deg(C) \cdot \deg(D)$ points, counting multiplicity. In particular, any two projective plane curves have nonempty intersection over an algebraically closed field. This implies that all projective plane curves over an algebraically closed field are connected (in the Zariski topology, but as Hoot's comment notes, this implies connectedness in the complex topology when $k = \mathbb{C}$).

More generally, dimension plays nicely with (set-theoretic) intersection over algebraically closed fields: Suppose $V$ and $W$ are irreducible closed subvarieties of $\mathbb{P}_k^n$. Then every irreducible component of $V \cap W$ has dimension at least $\dim(V) + \dim(W) - n$, and if $\dim(V) + \dim(W) - n \geq 0$, then $V \cap W$ is nonempty. Hence, any closed subvariety of $\mathbb{P}_k^n$ with all irreducible components of dimension at least $\frac{n}{2}$ is connected.